# How to output .o files into one specific folder?

Tags: c++, makefile, g++, mingw-w64

I'm currently using MinGW64, G++, and a makefile to compile my c++ project on VSCode. I have two src directories `src` and `src/vendor/imGui` containing .cpp files that I compile. As of now, the makefile is able to compile both src folders. However, the .o files are outputted in their respective src folders. How can I make it so that every .o file generated gets sent to one specific folder/directory?

Current Makefile:

```
CXX = g++

CXXFLAGS    := -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -g

LFLAGS += -LC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin
LFLAGS += -LC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib

OUTPUT  := output

SRC     := src
SRC     += src/vendor/imGui

INCLUDE := include

LIB     := lib

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
MAIN    := main.exe
SOURCEDIRS  := $(SRC)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(INCLUDE)
LIBDIRS     := $(LIB)
FIXPATH = $(subst /,\,$1)
RM          := del /q /f
MD  := mkdir
else
MAIN    := main
SOURCEDIRS  := $(shell find $(SRC) -type d)
INCLUDEDIRS := $(shell find $(INCLUDE) -type d)
LIBDIRS     := $(shell find $(LIB) -type d)
FIXPATH = $1
RM = rm -f
MD  := mkdir -p
endif

INCLUDES    := $(patsubst %,-I%, $(INCLUDEDIRS:%/=%))
INCLUDES    += -IC:/Users/kimda/Desktop/Projects/C++/Libraries/glm
INCLUDES    += -IC:/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include
INCLUDES    += -IC:/Users/kimda/Desktop/Projects/C++/OpenGL/src/vendor/imGui

LIBS        := $(patsubst %,-L%, $(LIBDIRS:%/=%))
LIBS        += -lglew32
LIBS        += -lopengl32
LIBS        += -lglfw3
LIBS        += -lgdi32
LIBS        += -lglu32

SOURCES     := $(wildcard $(patsubst %,%/*.cpp, $(SOURCEDIRS)))

OBJECTS     := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

OUTPUTMAIN  := $(call FIXPATH,$(OUTPUT)/$(MAIN))

all: $(OUTPUT) $(MAIN)
    @echo Building complete!
    

$(OUTPUT):
    @$(MD) $(OUTPUT)

$(MAIN): $(OBJECTS) 
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -o $(OUTPUTMAIN) $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) $(LIBS)

.cpp.o:
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) $(OUTPUTMAIN)
    @$(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(OBJECTS))
    @echo Cleanup complete!

run: clean all
    @./$(OUTPUTMAIN)
    @echo Executing complete!
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to send all object files to some 'build' directory.
I usually do something like this

```
BUILDDIR := build

[...]

OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))

[...]
```

and then change your

```
.cpp.o:
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $<  -o $@
```

to

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @$(MD) $(dir $@)
    @$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and now when I run the command `make clean` it comes up with this error: `The system cannot find the file specified.` for the `@$(RM) $(call FIXPATH,$(OBJECTS))` line. Also when I run the command `make` it comes up with this error: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.` for the `@$(MD) $(dir $@)` line.

Comment: the `clean` target can be simplified to just `rm build` now

Comment: for the incorrect syntax: check that the indentation is consistent and then take away the `@` and look at what it is trying to expand it too